# Parsing XML into hash with XML::Parser in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, hash, xml-parsing

I want to parse a simple XML document to hash.

```xml
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <book id = "bk101">
        <author>Bob</author>
        <title>Batman</title>
    </book>
    <book id = "bk102">
        <author>Jerry</author>
        <title>Superman</title>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

The expected output is something like the following.

```
$VAR1 = {
    'catalog'=>{
            'bk101'=>[
                  'author'=>'Bob',
                  'title'=>'Batman'
                  ]
            'bk102'=>[
                  'author'=>'Jerry',
                  'title'=>'Superman'
                  ]
        }
    }
```

I have done this with the help of `XML::Simple` and other libraries, but I have to do it with `XML::Parser`, without the use of recursion.

How would I do this in Perl?

Comment: First step is to read the documentation at https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Parser and follow it. Then show us your code, and tell us what exactly you're having problems with or what you don't understand about it.

Answer (score 2):

[XML::Hash::LX::xml2hash()](http://cpan.me/XML%3a%3aHash%3a%3aLX) is close to what you're looking for:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Hash::LX;

my $hash = xml2hash q(<?xml version ="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
        <book id = "bk101">
            <author>Bob</author>
            <title>Batman</title>
        </book>
        <book id = "bk102">
            <author>Jerry</author>
            <title>Superman</title>
        </book>
    </catalog>
);
print Dumper $hash;
```

Prints:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'catalog' => {
                       'book' => [
                                 {
                                   'title' => 'Batman',
                                   'author' => 'Bob',
                                   '-id' => 'bk101'
                                 },
                                 {
                                   'title' => 'Superman',
                                   'author' => 'Jerry',
                                   '-id' => 'bk102'
                                 }
                               ]
                     }
        };
```